# Waiting for async call (FaileSaver.async_save) to end with pygobject (gtk)

Tags: python, asynchronous, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

I'm using GtkSource for a small application.
When the user quit, I want to save all the buffer.

Unfortunately, if call FaileSaver.async_save for each buffer and then immediately call Gtk.main_loop, nothing is saved !

My solution now is to have a class :

```
class quit_callback():
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l

    def __call__(self):
        self.l -= 1
        if self.l == 0:
            Gtk.main_quit()
```

initialized with the number of buffers.

```
def _save_callback(self, file_saver, result, callback):
    file_saver.save_finish(result)
    callback()

def save(self, callback):
    if self._buffer is None:
        callback()
        return

    file_saver = GtkSource.FileSaver.new(self._buffer, self._file)
    file_saver.save_async(
        GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
        None,
        None,
        None,
        self._save_callback,
        callback
    )
```

So I call the save function for each model with the quit_callback instance as a parameter.

BUT, this is only a weak workaround : if another piece of code launched an async call, I don't wait for it to end... (and it doesn't seem thread safe)

Does someone know what is the best solution to wait for all async calls to end before calling Gtk.main_quit() ?

Thanks

Comment: Bypass all exit modes with your own(reboot,close(x), etc). Or periodic save (ex: save every 1 min)

Comment: Well, this does not solve the problem : in my own exit function I'll still have to call Gtk.main_quit() and to check if all async calls are finished.

Comment: Create status flag per function, when appear an exit change flag and thread condition(s). Or ignore all data (so save as last) for calling Gtk.main_quit(). If  destroy main body of your app can't save any data cos your thread holder app has ben destroyed.

Comment: Python has the GIL which I think should make any python code thread-safe. Besides, `_async` methods in Gtk will execute their callbacks in the main thread through the event loop